# How to tell if a virtual memory page has been locked?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-management, virtual-memory

Say, if at some point a range of the virtual memory in my process was locked as such:

```
//Memory was reserved & committed as such
void* pMem = ::VirtualAlloc(NULL, 4096, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

//...

//And then
::VirtualLock(pMem, 4096);
```

So having an arbitrary address of a page in a virtual memory in my process, can I tell if it was [`locked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by using win32 api this is impossible. but if use [`ZwQueryVirtualMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn957455(v=vs.85).aspx) with **undocumented** [`MEMORY_INFORMATION_CLASS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn957516(v=vs.85).aspx) values - this is possible. for data structures definition - see [ntmmapi.h](https://github.com/processhacker2/processhacker2/blob/master/phnt/include/ntmmapi.h)

we need use [`MemoryWorkingSetExInformation`](https://github.com/processhacker2/processhacker2/blob/master/phnt/include/ntmmapi.h#L65) with [`MEMORY_WORKING_SET_EX_BLOCK`](https://github.com/processhacker2/processhacker2/blob/master/phnt/include/ntmmapi.h#L129) and use `ULONG_PTR Locked : 1;` member

demo test:

```
NTSTATUS IsPageLocked(PVOID BaseAddress, BOOLEAN& Locked)
{
    MEMORY_WORKING_SET_EX_INFORMATION mwsei = { BaseAddress };

    NTSTATUS status = ZwQueryVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), 0, MemoryWorkingSetExInformation, &mwsei, sizeof(mwsei), 0);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        if (mwsei.VirtualAttributes.Valid)
        {
            Locked = mwsei.VirtualAttributes.Locked;
        }
        else
        {
            status = STATUS_INVALID_ADDRESS;
        }
    }

    return status;
}

NTSTATUS IsPageLockedEx(PVOID BaseAddress, BOOLEAN& Locked)
{
    NTSTATUS status = IsPageLocked(BaseAddress, Locked);
    if (0 > status)
    {
        DbgPrint("IsPageLocked - error %x\n", status);
    }
    else
    {
        DbgPrint("IsPageLocked = %x\n", Locked);
    }
    return status;
}

void CheckVA()
{
    if (PVOID pv = VirtualAlloc(NULL, PAGE_SIZE, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE))
    {
        BOOLEAN Locked;
        NTSTATUS status = IsPageLockedEx(pv, Locked);

        if (status == STATUS_INVALID_ADDRESS)
        {
            // at this point  physical memory for pv not yet committed. reference memory for commit physical page
            if (*(PBYTE)pv) __nop();

            status = IsPageLockedEx(pv, Locked);
        }

        if (VirtualLock(pv, PAGE_SIZE))
        {
            IsPageLockedEx(pv, Locked);

            if (VirtualUnlock(pv, PAGE_SIZE))
            {
                IsPageLockedEx(pv, Locked);
            }
            else
            {
                __debugbreak();
            }
        }

        VirtualFree(pv, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    }
}
```

and *DbgPrint* output

```
IsPageLocked - error c0000141
IsPageLocked = 0
IsPageLocked = 1
IsPageLocked = 0
```

Comment: Very nice find. Thank you. I'm curious though, why didn't Microsoft expose an official API to do this?

Comment: @c00000fd - think this is very rare when need to know (exactly when page is locked). `VirtualQueryEx` only exist which is tiny shell over `ZwQueryVirtualMemory` with hard-coded information class *MemoryBasicInformation* - and only this class and documented. however some another infoclass for my look is very useful in same case - say *MemoryMappedFilenameInformation* or *MemoryWorkingSetInformation*.

Comment: Just to expand. I confirmed experimentally that this method works starting with `Windows Vista` and any later OS. (So no `XP` support, if it matters.) Also if anyone wants to load `ZwQueryVirtualMemory` dynamically, [here's an example](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/41092-how-to-use-ntqueryvirtualmemory-to-get-loaded-dlls/?p=10096341) how.

Comment: @c00000fd - `ZwQueryVirtualMemory` can be called exactly as any exported api from another dll. how you call `VirtualQuery` for example ? simply link with `kernel32.lib`. for `ntdll.dll` - simply link to `ntdll[p].lib` which is in `wdk` (installed in same way and to same folders as `sdk`). and this is *documented* in msdn api. for kernel mode only ? but how from user mode `VirtualQuery[Ex]` work ?

Comment: What wouldn't work in Windows XP is `MemoryWorkingSetExInformation` flag.

Comment: @c00000fd no, `ZwQueryVirtualMemory` - exist and in `xp`, and `win2000` and even in `nt4` - so you can statically link to it without any errors. if you will be use `MemoryWorkingSetExInformation` flag on `xp`, you simply got  `STATUS_INVALID_INFO_CLASS` error , but this is absolute unrelated  for static or dynamic you will be link to `ntdll.dll`

Comment: OK, sure. What I'm saying is that without `MemoryWorkingSetExInformation` flag your method will not work on XP.

Comment: @c00000fd - yes, on `xp` this is yet not supported. however `xp` now already official not supported

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this in the future, XP and later now include APIs that do this: [QueryWorkingSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-queryworkingset) and [QueryWorkingSetEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-queryworkingsetex).

Look for the `Locked` bit in the [PSAPI_WORKING_SET_EX_BLOCK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/ns-psapi-psapi_working_set_ex_block) structure, similar to the answer relying on ZwQueryVirtualMemory.